# Beginning android: how to map a string to a list

Tags: android, string, list, key

I just finished the NotepadV1-3 tutorial for Android apps, and I was thinking of creating my own inventory app for fun, which for now basically consists of a list of names (such as "DVD" or "Grocery"), each of which can be clicked, which will bring up another specific list associated with that name. However, with the SQLiteDatabase.insert(..) method, the ContentValue can only take (among many others) "String, String" as argument, and I can't figure out how to input into the database a list of Strings associated with a particular key. I'm having trouble researching on how to resolve this as I am not that familiar with SQL.

What would be the best way to store a key with its associated list of Strings?

Any pointers and suggestions are appreciated!

Android newb :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you could is to make a database-design that doesn't need you to input the list as as "string of strings". You might (I have not thought this trough all the way) have a table with lists (id and listName) and another table with contents (id and contentName) and finally a table that connects the two (tableId and contentName).

If you REALLY want to store that string-of-strings, you could serialize it into one string, and then when you've read it from the db, you can rebuild the string. This is NOT recommended though.

Example for a (simpler) database

```
Table 1 "lists": listId, listName
Table 2 "items": itemId, itemName, listId
```

e.g.:

```
Lists:
listId  listName
1       DVD's
2       Grocery

Items
itemId   itemName   listId
1        film1      1
2        film2      1
3        sugar      2
4        milk       2
```

You can find all items of the grocery list by:

```
SELECT i.itemName 
FROM lists l 
JOIN items i ON l.listId = i.listId
WHERE l.listName='Grocery'
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess tokenize/rebuild string would be my backup plan, since I'm not really going for efficiency as of right now, just doing it for fun and seeing how Android framework works.

I'm not sure how I would link the two tables, especially when different lists will have different numbers of elements, etc., unless I create a new table for each list.

Comment: see added example for quick sollution with 2 tables :)